# Can FB.ui's Property 'Picture' can fetch an Image from a HttpHandler?

Tags: facebook, feed, httphandler, image, fb.ui

Can FB.ui's 'Picture' Attribute fetch an image data from a custom Httphandler (wrtitten in .net) or Facebook mandates the image path to be a server path. The code I am trying to execute is something like this:

```
 FB.ui(
                  {
                      method: 'feed',
                      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                      link: 'http://mydemosite/',
                      picture: 'http://mydemosite.com/PromoImage.ashx?id=3',
                      caption: 'My Promo',
                      description: pDescription
                  },
                  function (response) {
                      if (response && response.post_id) {
                          alert('Post was published.');
                      } else {
                          alert('Post was not published.');
                      }
                  }
            );
```

Need help in this regard.

Regards

Abhishek

Comment: It's been a day, did you try yet?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an anwser to this to. I have almost the exact same code and my image is not showing in the feed dialog. i get all the other stuff to show but there is no image. I am using an ashx handler to stream image from database.
There is no error or anything the image just doesnt appear. 
Anyone has an anwser to this?

Comment: Put your image’s URL through Facebook debugger.